# "Rename in file" error in Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code

```
Data currentNode = treeList.get(i);
Collections.sort(currentNode.childrenList, new Comparator<Data>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Data object1, final Data object2) {
        return object1.getNodeName().compareTo(object2.getNodeName());
    }
   } 
);
```

But `.sort` is underlined in red and Eclipse is suggesting `Rename in file`.

What does this ambiguous error mean?

Note if I do:
`Collections.sort(treeList...` instead of `Collections.sort(currentNode.childrenList...`
the error disappears even though `treeList` and `childrenList` are virtually the same.

Comment: What type is `treeList`? Can you post the code for the `Data` class?

Comment: `treeList` is this `public static List<Data> treeList = new ArrayList<Data>();`

Data has `public String nodeName;
 double heuristic;
    public List<Children> childrenList = new ArrayList<Children>();` and a bunch of methods.

Comment: Also, what is the compiler error message? Being underlined in red doesn't tell us much about the actual error.

Comment: How do you expect to sort `Children` objects with a comparator that takes `Data` objects?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Children>, new Comparator<Data>(){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to sort a `List<Children>` with a `Comparator<Data>`. That's why you get an error. A `List<Children>` should be sorted using a `Comparator<Children>`, or a `Comparator<SomethingThatChildrenExtendsOrImplements>`.

In non-computer terms, you're trying to sort bananas with something that compares apples. Sorting bananas can be done with something able to sort bananas, or with something able to sort any kind of fruit.

Comment: Ah what an oversight. Thank you, it looked fine to me but I just didn't pick up on that. 

Thanks again.